# How to view post/put/patch data

Tags: kibana, elastic-apm

When error occurs, I want to see the data payload uploaded by users.

I wasn't able to find the `post/put/patch` data in apm report. (kibana)

Is there an option I need to turn on for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most agents have a [CaptureBody](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/config-core.html#config-capture-body) config option, with that you can capture the request body. It's off by default - you can set it to `error`.

I linked the Java docs, you should be able to find the same config for (I think all) other agents.